# Does jq support muliple -f options?

Tags: jq

```
==> main.jq <==
def myflattern:
  .[];

==> main2.jq <==
myflattern
```

Given the above jq files, I see the following output. So `jq` does not support multiple `-f`? Thanks.

```
$ jq -f main.jq -f main2.jq <<EOF
[ "a", "b", "c" ]
EOF
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0

$ jq -f <(cat main.jq main2.jq) <<EOF
[ "a", "b", "c" ]
EOF
"a"
"b"
"c"
```

Comment: No. But see https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @OguzIsmail, jq does not support more than one occurrence of `-f` per invocation, but there are potentially two (complementary) workarounds:

1. If your shell allows it, you can use process substitution:

   `jq -f <(cat ....) ...`
2. You can use the jq module system.

Note that there can be only one "main" in a jq program, and that jq modules can only include function definitions.